# Add Program or Process Name to Avast Exclusions

Tags: avast

In Avast, is it possible (and does it work) to exclude an executable *by name*, without having to specify the whole path?  For example, adding just `devenv.exe` versus adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`.

Avast v12.3.x on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Could you just try it and see if it's work?